live_grep on Neovim is not working as expected even after installing ripgrep and fdfind. Neovim cannot find them in external dependencies
I'm new to neovim and trying to get started with configuring my system. I am running Debian system and have flatpak'd Neovim. I think this may be a cause for the issue I am facing. This is my current 'init.lua' file.
vim.cmd("set expandtab")
vim.cmd("set tabstop=4")
vim.cmd("set softtabstop=4")
vim.cmd("set shiftwidth=4")
vim.g.mapleader = " "

local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not (vim.uv or vim.loop).fs_stat(lazypath) then
  vim.fn.system({
    "git",
    "clone",
    "--filter=blob:none",
    "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git",
    "--branch=stable", -- latest stable release
    lazypath,
  })
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

local plugins = {
    { "catppuccin/nvim", name = "catppuccin", priority = 1000 },
    {
      'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim', tag = '0.1.6',
      dependencies = { 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim' }
    }
}
local opts = {}

vim.env.PATH = '/usr/bin:' .. vim.env.PATH

require("lazy").setup(plugins, opts)
local builtin = require("telescope.builtin")
vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-p>', builtin.find_files, {})
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>fg', builtin.live_grep, {})

require("catppuccin").setup()
vim.cmd.colorscheme "catppuccin"

I am using Lazy. I have already installed ripgrep and fd. But when I run 'checkhealth telescope'. I get this:
==============================================================================
telescope: require("telescope.health").check()

Checking for required plugins ~
- OK plenary installed.
- WARNING nvim-treesitter not found. 

Checking external dependencies ~
- ERROR rg: not found. `live-grep` finder will not function without [BurntSushi/ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) installed.
- WARNING fd: not found. Install [sharkdp/fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) for extended capabilities

===== Installed extensions ===== ~

Both ripgrep and fd binaries are in this location:
❯ which rg && which fdfind
/usr/bin/rg
/usr/bin/fdfind

And if I check the PATH for the 'init.lua':
/usr/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin:/home/boibhav/.var/app/io.neovim.nvim/data/node/bin:/home/boibhav/.var/app/io.neovim.nvim/data/cargo/bin:/home/boibhav/.var/app/io.neovim.nvim/data/python/bin:/home
/boibhav/.var/app/io.neovim.nvim/data/gem/ruby/3.2.0/bin

The file search view does open but on enterring any search query I don't see any results. Can someone please help me with this? Thank you for your time.

I have the same setup, Debian with Flatpak Neovim. I found and installed this and it seems to work: https://github.com/iruzo/ripgrep.nvim

Did you try using brew to install them ?
brew install ripgrep
brew install fd
